# Moving the position of the back item in a UINavigationBar iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

Trying to move the position of the back item on the UINavigationBar by getting a handle to the backbutton however I only seem to be able to make it disappear rather than do anything with it

I have the following in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title =@"Testing";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title= @"1234";
```

They do not work however

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Works as you would expect, looking through the documentation it looks like higher up the backItem might be readonly is this the case?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem; // readonly
```

Any pointers on how to move this in approx 30 pixels much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  However, you can define a custom button (with back functionality) and place it wherever you want on the nav bar.  Then simply hide the back button